# Why this xpath is not found

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

when i open with inspect element i see code like this:

```
<div spellcheck="false" unselectable="off" class="appmagic-label-text" data-control-part="text" data-bind="{
            inlineEditText: properties.Text,
            css: {
              'appmagic-label-single-line': !properties.Wrap()
            },
            attr: {
              'aria-live': live,
              'aria-atomic': live() ? 'true' : null
            }
          }">Atostogų prašymai</div>
```

and i'm trying to get this text "atostogų prašymai" xpath and there is no way I can find it.

options i have tryied:

1. `By.cssSelector("div[class='appmagic-label-text']");`
2. Just copied xpath `By.cssSelector("div[class='//*[@id=\"publishedCanvas\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div']");`

css screen:
[image]

iframe code is visible:

```
<iframe class="publishedAppIframe" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" id="fullscreen-app-host" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="fullscreen-app-host" src="https://pa-content.azureedge.net/resource/webplayerdynamic/publishedapp/preloadindex?preloadIndexPath=https%3A%2F%2Fcontent.powerapps.com%2Fresource%2Fapp%2Fupuvepsd66qk3%2Fpreloadindex.web.html&amp;PowerAppsLanguage=en-US&amp;loader=inline&amp;lv=jpigefv5ue8uc&amp;serviceWorkerUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpa-content.azureedge.net%2Fresource%2Fwebplayer%2Fhashedresources%2Fqqhtjvhh4omr6%2Fjs%2FPowerAppsServiceWorker.PublishedApp.js&amp;piv=796D32DE&amp;featureGates={&quot;publishedAppServiceWorker&quot;:false}#%7B%22platform%22%3A%22notwindows%22%2C%22hideNavBar%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22antiCSRFToken%22%3A%22f01dae6c-0d74-4f48-8a74-95b9ee3d5943%22%2C%22cdnUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcontent.powerapps.com%2Fresource%2Fapp%22%2C%22paramsQuery%22%3A%22tenantId%3Dde6e25a9-36c4-424d-af6b-431db29f6cfe%26appId%3D%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.PowerApps%2Fapps%2Fff261fd6-5458-4a3f-8697-f50ff8a1ff06%22%2C%22iframeMode%22%3Anull%2C%22packagePropertiesVersion%22%3A%222.1%22%2C%22staticContentProxy%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcontent.powerapps.com%2Fresource%2Fwebplayerdynamic%2Fproxy%2Fstaticcontent%3FstaticContentPath%3D%22%2C%22launchFunctionUrlFormat%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapps.powerapps.com%2Fplay%2F%7B0%7D%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22prod%22%2C%22staticContentUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.powerapps.com%22%7D" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; fullscreen" style="" title="Atostogos"></iframe>
```

and there is methods related with iframe i think:

```
public void selectIframe() {
        String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String childHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!childHandle.equals(parent)) {
                driver.switchTo().frame(childHandle);
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectParentFrame() {
        driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
    }
```

how can i use them in this situation?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to select it by its class alone: `By.cssSelector(".appmagic-label-text")` Regarding your XPath attempt, you can't use an XPath expression inside a string, but it might work if you remove the start and end `'`s. Why is your XPath attempt so much more complicated than your CSS attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have messed up with css selector and xpath.

your xpath should be

```
By.Xpath("//div[@class='appmagic-label-text']")
```

Or more generic

```
By.Xpath("//div[@class='appmagic-label-text'][text()='Atostogų prašymai']")
```

Or

```
  By.cssSelector("div.appmagic-label-text")
```

---

Update:
Since element inside iframe you need to switch it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("fullscreen-app-host")));
WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='appmagic-label-text']")));
```

To jump out from iframe you need to use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but xpath is still not found: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='appmagic-label-text'] (tried for 60 second(s) with 50 milliseconds interval

Comment: Well element could be inside iframe? Could you please check DOM?

Comment: If url is public please share your url?

Comment: i don't see the iframe. I have posted image into description of css, or maybe would be better something else ?

Comment: Ok try with presence of element located possibly element is not visible on the page. If you get same error then check if there shadow-root element?

Comment: sorry, right now i see about iframe. i have added to description

Comment: @Jetz: which language are you binding? java?

Comment: @Jetz : Check my updated answer and let me know how this goes?

Comment: okey, right now i'm trying to understand where to add these two lines.

Comment: @JetZ : where you are identifying the particular element replace that code with those two lines.

Comment: sorry, can you check description, i added methods of iframe i have on my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230652/discussion-between-kunduk-and-jetz).

Answer (score 1):

use the xpath as below

```
//div[@class='appmagic-label-text'][contains(.,'Atostogų prašymai')]
```

Always build your own xpath. To explain here // stands for relative path, div is the tag, [ stands condition start,@class=''appmagic-label-text' is the query, ] condition end,again here I used another condition as or .[ condition starts , Contains query for finding anything that contains, . stand for anything, matches 'Atostogų prašymai'.

Please note I did not use text so that it will find anything that matches 'Atostogų prašymai' and starts with div tag which has a class appmagic-label-text.

There are many xpath build also available. you may use that. but its always better to build your own xpath